# Microdata - How to markup Item properties placed inside a child Item (and therefore out of it's scope)

Tags: html, semantic-web, semantic-markup, microdata, schema.org

Is there any way to markup Item properties placed inside a child Item (and therefore out of it's scope)?

I'm using microdata and schema.org to mark up some web page with. and I have a code like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">

        <a href="index.html">
            <img id="logo" src="xxx" alt="xxx" itemprop="primaryImageOfPage">
        </a>

    </header>

    <!--the rest of the page-->
</body>
```

I have the logo inside the WPHeader Item and I want it to be the primaryImageOfPage for the WebPage Item. I know i can use Itemref to include properties which are out of the item's scope, but like this you don't take this property out of the child item's scope. That's really a problem if both items can have the same property, such as name or description.

This is only an example to explain the problem I have. By the moment I solve it using itemref...but there has to be a better way to do that.

I know there's no need to markup everything, I just want to know which is the best way to avoid having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microdata is RDFa rip-off constrained to be relevant to search cross-cutting concern for semantic fragments. It thus assumes the advanced scoping abilities of CURIEs is discardable. For wholeness that good quality domain-specific content pages exhibit, **RDFa alongwith vocab covering domain-specific aspects accordingly is the ultimate way as yet**. While search providers dominated HTML5 spec to make microdata part of standard, as the Web keeps growing more semantic, the differences between both are ending up as mere matter of "what's in a name?"

Comment: You couldn't have explained it better. Thanks a lot for your answer. My question wasn't actually a real problem I was facing; but I felt I needed to know such things and start moving towards the semantic web.

Comment: Humbled to be acquainted with someone coping with similar things.